# MySQL Workbench creates extra index

Tags: mysql, indexing, workbench

When I use MySQL Workbench to create a simple table with a single primary key, it not only creates the PK index (cool) but also a second Unique Index (?). Here's an example output:

```
CREATE  TABLE  `tbl_example` (
  `tbl_example_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `field1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `field2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tbl_example_ID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `tbl_example_ID_UNIQUE` (`tbl_example_ID` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

It's my understanding that a PK assumes unique index so the `UNIQUE INDEX` line is unnecessary, correct? Just looking for some confirmation before I update a bunch of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. A Primary Key is (for MySQL) a unique index with the name 'PRIMARY KEY'. So having a Primary Key and a unique index on the same column(s) is a pointless waste of resources.